# Ktor 1.3.0-beta-1 multiplatform - SSL pinning for iOS in kotlin

Tags: ssl, kotlin, pinning

I'm using `ktor-1.3.0-beta-1`

I need to add a few `NSURLSessionDelegate` checks for SSL Pinning.

I need exactly the code I found here [Ktor multiplatform - SSL pinning for iOS in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777854/ktor-multiplatform-ssl-pinning-for-ios-in-kotlin), in a Multiplatform app I'm working on (I try to migrate some stuff from native APP to a Multiplatform library).

I'm pretty new to Kotlin, so I don't have full knowledge of how it works.

I want to ask you: where have I to put this code?

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: I found `IosClientEngineConfig` where you can modify a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` but I'm not sure how to add pinning and self-signed certificates to it?!