# Ktor client IOS and self-signed certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, ktor, kotlin-native

I'm using Ktor and Kotlin/native in iOS in an iOS app that accesses an internal dev server. The dev server uses a certificate issued by an internal CA which is not publicly trusted.

When trying to access the server with the following code :

```
  internal suspend fun performHttp(url : String)
    {
        // URL is a self signed HTTPS: request
        val client = HttpClient(Ios) 

        val response = client.get<String>(url)
        println(response)
    }
```

it throws the following exception :

```
TIC SSL Trust Error [32:0x281956dc0]: 3:0
esri2[470:136341] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)
esri2[470:136341] Task <F3CC4C40-0231-4E58-97F3-F457D5A18BB0>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9807])
 esri2[470:136417] Task <F3CC4C40-0231-4E58-97F3-F457D5A18BB0>.<1> finished with error - code: -1202
esri2[470:136211] Task <F3CC4C40-0231-4E58-97F3-F457D5A18BB0>.<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server1.internal.lan” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x12b094e00) s: server1.internal.lan i: Internal-Issuing-CA2>",
```

How do I convince Ktor that it should access this URL, or ignore untrusted certs? Yes, I know that one should not ignore untrusted certs, but this is a lab test.

Comment: Check out this, might do the trick for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/5147552

Comment: I had already tried that, I did not mention that in my post. I have added the domain to  NSExceptionDomains list with NSIncludesSubdomains = true and NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true. It doesn't look like Ktor is using that config. 
The workaround so far was to export the internal root CA as a pem file , and email it to my iPhone ,install it and trust it (https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/self-signed-certificates-in-ios-apps-ff489bf8b96e).

I hope there is a better solution to this in Ktor.

Comment: Hi, did you find a real solution?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm still hoping there are some better solution to this problem

Answer (score 2):

[Ktor iOS engine](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#ios) offers the ability to configure the underlying [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession) with the help of [IosClientEngineConfig.kt](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-client/ktor-client-ios/darwin/src/io/ktor/client/engine/ios/IosClientEngineConfig.kt).

With it you can configure (amongst other things) a `ChallengeHandler` by setting the block for `handleChallenge` in the [config](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#ios) like this:

```
val client = HttpClient(Ios) {
    engine {
        handleChallenge(TrustSelfSignedCertificate())
    }
}
```

Then you need to implement a class in Kotlin something like this:

```
internal data class TrustSelfSignedCertificate internal constructor(
    private val validateTrust: Boolean = true
) : ChallengeHandler {

    override fun invoke(
        session: NSURLSession,
        task: NSURLSessionTask,
        challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
        completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Unit
    ) {
        val hostname = challenge.protectionSpace.host

        val serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
        var result: SecTrustResultType = 0u

        memScoped {
            val nativeResult = alloc<SecTrustResultTypeVar>()
            nativeResult.value = result
            SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust!!, nativeResult.ptr)
        }

        val serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)
        val serverCertificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(serverCertificate)
        val data = CFDataGetBytePtr(serverCertificateData)
        val size = CFDataGetLength(serverCertificateData)

        val cert1 = NSData.dataWithBytes(data, size.toULong())
        val pathToCert = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("myOwnCert", "cer")

        val localCertificate: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(pathToCert!!)!!

        if (localCertificate == cert1) {
            completionHandler(
                NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,
                NSURLCredential.create(serverTrust)
            )
        } else {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to put you certificate as a file "myOwnCert.cer" into you iOS project (maybe on the top-level).

---

**NOTE**

Ktor with iOS engine does not respect/use [NSApptransportSecurity](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1671).

---

The code is based on this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58777854/332248).

With the help of this [blog-post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/kotlin-multiplatform-ios-certificate-pinning-fd1abba5ca8f).